# Confusing in Campaign measurement in GA Android SDK

Tags: android-intent, google-analytics

I'm reading the Campaign measurement in GA Android SDK.
In the sample code(https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/campaigns), 
it looks google play issues an Intent with Uri and the Receiver retrieve the Uri and set Campaign parameters.

I'm confusing in:
The Google Play only send one Intent to the Receiver.
So.. the Receiver only set Campaign parameters for only one time.
After the app got downloaded, the app can be launch by manually click in home screen.
How can it measure the app is credit to the original campaign for a period of time?

Does it mean.. the GA library will store those campaign parameters in device until next alternative campaign appeared?

In my experiment, my app did receive the Intent and set campaign parameters.
In this app life, only the 1st tracking is with campaign parameters.

Then, I closed my app and launch it again. It didn't receive Intent anymore and the subsequent GA trackings will not with campaign parameters.

Shall I add code to set campaign parameters in every app life??  How to do that?
Or GA server will use the campaign parameter in the last tracking as the effective campaign ??

Any comment will be very appreciated.

Kevin Kuei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe GA server should use the campaign parameter in the last tracking as the effective campaign unless it's being over-ride. You can cross check with your apps visit against campaign source.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the intent you are talking about is fired upon the first initiation of the app, and not as the installation finishes(in contrary to what the docs state).
that's why it is called `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER`

After the first app open you will never get it again(for the obvious reasons)